парсинг плейлиста вк
Я новичок, сильно не ругайте)
Мне нужно спарсить данные с плейлиста в вк
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне достать название плейлиста, имя автора и количество прослушиваний
Сейчас у меня есть вот такой код
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r'https://vk.com/al_audio.php'
params = {'act': 'load_section'}
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
data = {
    'al': 1,
    'owner_id': 830992679,
    'playlist_id': 13,
    'type': 'playlist'
}
req = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers, params=params)

print (req.text)

Помогите достать все что нужно, пожалуйста

print (req.json()['payload'][1][0]['title'])

Спасибо большое
